# How can I use Promise.all with multiple arguments?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I just started with Node.js. I have this code where i take the salary and the number of days and then calculate the average money you can spend per day until you get your next salary(5th of the month). The first promise is used to validate the user input and the second one actually calculates the result after the first promise is fulfilled. The code below works fine but i want to use Promise.all to get a deeper understanding of the topic.

```
var prompt = require('prompt');

prompt.start();

var promise1 = function(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        prompt.get(['salary','day'],function(err,result){
            var x = result.salary;
            var y = result.day;
            var z =  /^[0-9]*$/;

            if(x.match(z) && y.match(z))
            {
                resolve(result);
            }
            else{
                reject('invalid day or salary');
            }

        })
    })
}

var promise2 = function(x,y){
    //console.log('x is ' + x);
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        if(y>=1 && y<5){
            var z = x/(5-y);
            resolve(z);
        }
        else if(y<=30 && y>5){
            var z = x/(35-y);
            resolve(z);
        }
        else{
            reject('day not within range...');
        }
    })
}



promise1().then(function(resolve){
    return promise2(resolve.salary,resolve.day);

}).then(function(resolve){
    console.log(resolve);
}).catch(function(fromReject){
    console.log(fromReject);
})
```

Comment: `Promise.all` does not allow you to use result of one promise in another.

Comment: All the promises start executing at once and you get a callback once all of the promises are resolved.

Comment: What makes you think that you could use `Promise.all` here?

Comment: Please don't call the parameter of a `then` callback "`resolve`". It's a *result*, not a resolving function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Promise.all` is not the function you need when you have a dependency between the promises you intend to pass as arguments to it. Whenever you need the promised value from one promise to create the next, `Promise.all` is not an option. The way you do it with `then` is how it is done (but don't call the result `resolve`). You could also use `async` and `await` to achieve the same.

As only the first promise has asynchronous code, there is not really a necessity for the second promise to be there at all. But if you really want it to be a promise, then return `Promise.resolve`, not a `new Promise`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: Yes it does .So Promise.all is used when the promises are independent of each other

Comment: Indeed, it is like that. In that case, they can be executed all immediately.